# How to use wiktextract

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a Wiktionary `xml` file from their dumps using the wiktextract python module. However their website does not give me enough information. I could not use the command line program that comes with it since it isn't a Windows executable, so I tried the programmatic way. The following code takes a while to run so it seems to be doing something but then I'm not sure what to do with the `ctx` variable. Can anyone help me?

```
import wiktextract

def word_cb(data):
    print(data) 

ctx = wiktextract.parse_wiktionary(
    r'myfile.xml', word_cb,
    languages=["English", "Translingual"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but don't have to worry too much about the `ctx` object. 
As the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/wiktextract/) says:

> The parse_wiktionary call will call `word_cb(data)` for words and redirects found in the 
>   Wiktionary dump. `data` is information about a single word and part-of-speech as a dictionary (multiple senses of the same part-of-speech are combined into the same dictionary). It may also be a redirect (indicated by presence of a `redirect` key in the dictionary).

The output `ctx` object mostly contains summary information (the number of sections processed, etc; you can use `dir(ctx)` to see some of its fields.

The useful results are not the ones in the returned `ctx` object, but the ones passed to `word_cb` on a word-by-word basis. So you might just try something like the following to get a JSON dump from a wiktionary XML dump. Because the full dumps are many gigabytes, I put a small one on a server for convenience in this example.

```
import json
import wiktextract

import requests

xml_fn = 'enwiktionary-20190220-pages-articles-sample.xml'

print("Downloading XML dump to " + xml_fn)

response = requests.get('http://45.61.148.79/' + xml_fn, stream=True)

# Throw an error for bad status codes
response.raise_for_status()

with open(xml_fn, 'wb') as handle:
    for block in response.iter_content(4096):
        handle.write(block)

print("Downloaded XML dump, beginning processing...")

fh = open("output.json", "wb")
def word_cb(data):
    fh.write(json.dumps(data))

ctx = wiktextract.parse_wiktionary(
    r'enwiktionary-20190220-pages-articles-sample.xml', word_cb,
    languages=["English", "Translingual"])

print("{} English entries processed.".format(ctx.language_counts["English"]))
print("{} bytes written to output.json".format(fh.tell()))

fh.close()
```

For me this produces:

```
Downloading XML dump to enwiktionary-20190220-pages-articles-sample.xml
Downloaded XML dump, beginning processing...
684 English entries processed.
326478 bytes written to output.json
```

with the small dump extract I placed on a server for convenience. It will take much longer to run on the full dump.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a complete script that worked for me-- although on Linux; it sounds like you are using Windows.

Comment: Gives me: 0 English entries processed. 0 bytes written to output.json. Maybe it's failing because I'm doing Afrikaans and not English.

Comment: If I replace "English" with "Afrikaans" in the above, I still get 15 entries processed. I wonder whether you are doing something differently, or whether you have a systems problem.